# VAT refund London Heathrow

Tags: uk

I recently visited London and did some shopping and got my vat refund processed at Heathrow from Travelex by booking a personal appointment.

By mistake one receipt and form has come back with me to India. Is there any way of getting that refund now or on my next trip which will be maybe in year or so.

Answer (score 6):

No, you have to get the form stamped at your point of exit from the EU with the item available for inspection. Even if you brought the item back with you:

> you can only get VAT refunds for goods bought within the last 3
>   months.

https://www.gov.uk/tax-on-shopping/taxfree-shopping